# Setting SOAP header using PHP SoapClient.php. Header elements are not enclosed inside any tag

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

This is my service header

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:la="http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj">
    <la:AID>Bach</la:AID>
    <la:CID>TT2569</la:CID>
    <la:CuID>ABC</la:CuID>
    <la:CaID>12235</la:CaID>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I am setting the header in my php code like this:

```
$soapenv = array(
    'AID' => 'Bach',
    'CID'=>'TT2569',
    'CuID'=>'ABC', 
    'CaID'=>'12235'
);

$header = new SoapHeader('http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj', 'la', $soapenv, false);

$temp=new SoapClient($url, array());

$temp->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```

On calling service, I am getting the soap fault as if I have not set the header
Can somebody rectify mistakes, I have been doing?

Here is the code which get me going. I am not aware of the possibility of better code, please enlighten me, if there exists one.

Replaced

```
$header = new SoapHeader('http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj', 'la', $soapenv, false);
```

with

```
$header = array(
new SoapHeader('http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj', 'CID', 'TT2569', false), 
new SoapHeader('http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj', 'CaID', '12235', false), 
new SoapHeader('http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj', 'AID', 'Bach', false), 
new SoapHeader('http://ccc.xxx.zzz.jjj', 'CuID', 'ABC', false)
);
```

Comment: Try removing `array` from the line `setSoapHeaders`?

Comment: @uncle-junky Tried, no luck. Same error as in prev case.

Comment: I have found the solution and added it in the question asked